# Is there an ImageMagick function that figures out if filetype is supported or not?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have an array of file paths that I need ImageMagick to run through.

But some of the files are files that are not supported by ImageMagick, aborts the loop and gives me "Uncaught exception" errors. I'd like to just skip those files and move on to the next one, but I can't find any information on this.

This is my loop:

```
// I'd like this section to be inclosed in a function that decides
// if Imagemagick should skip the file or do the thumbnail process
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($wpdm_uploads_folder . $file);
$filename = ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/thumbs/';

if ( ! is_wp_error( $imagick ) ) {
    if($new_file['extension'] == "psd"){
        $imagick->setIteratorIndex(0);
    }
    $imagick->thumbnailImage(200, 0);
    $imagick->writeImage($filename . $new_file['filename'] . '.png');
}

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();
```

Comment: Why not just catch the exception and `continue` the loop?

Comment: That sounds like it could work, but I don't know the theory around it. I'll do some googling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Imagick::pingImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.pingimage.php) is your friend for getting information about a possible image. Ping image just looks at the image's header and meta-info, and doesn't load any actual image-data. Checkout article ["to Ping, or not to Ping."](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#identify_ping)

```php
<?php

$images = array(
    'built-in' => 'rose:',
    'valid' => '/tmp/image.png',
    'invalid' => '/tmp/server.sock',
);

$wand = new Imagick();
foreach( $images as $type => $path ) {
    try {
        $okay = $wand->pingImage($path);
    } catch (ImagickException $error) {
        $okay = FALSE;
    }
    if($okay) {
        print $path . ' is an image' . PHP_EOL;
        print $path . ' has a format of ' . $wand->getImageFormat() . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        print $path . ' is NOT an image' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

outputs ...

```
rose: is an image
rose: has a format of PPM
/tmp/out.png is an image
/tmp/out.png has a format of PNG
/tmp/server.sock is NOT an image
```

*Edit*

If you want to know the supported image formats of the system's ImageMagick library *before* working with files. [Imagick::queryFormats](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryformats.php) can generate a list built-in, formats, and types.

Comment: that's very interesting, but would it be able to tell when imagemagick throws an error? sometimes imagemagick will throw an error for an image as well, as there might be something else wrong with it..

Comment: Throwing an ImagickException is the desired behavior. It's up to your client code to evaluate when/what/where. See the [error codes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/exception.php) for exception details.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but the exceptions are most likely triggered by the files, so wouldn't it be better just to bypass them to complete the process? The bypassed files are no issue for me as I can create them manually, although it wouldn't hurt putting them in an array so I knew which files I should create manually.

Comment: @michaelw90 you could build out a whitelist, or blacklist, before working with images. But exception handling _needs_ to be including in your solution, and you should not trust file-extensions for uploaded content.

Comment: Also, you may find that while a certain filetype is supported, one or more of its subtypes is not supported - so it would become enormously complicated to decide. For example, ImageMagick supports `BMP` files but it decidely dislikes some `BMP` variants and cannot, for love nor money, be coerced into generating some combinations. Likewise, there are Adobe and GeoTIFF variants of TIFs that may cause problems although ImageMagick is fine with 99% of normal TIFFs.

Answer (score 0):

For a command line approach, my first proposal would be to use

```
identify -ping -format "%m\n" filename
```

and then check return value and output on `<stdout>` for the magic file type. *(This is probably the very same approach @emcconville used with PHP)*.

However, I've not tested this on a wide range of different file formats (yet).